# How to pass string[] as a parameter to solidity function?

Tags: node.js, arrays, solidity, ethers.js

I'm trying to pass a string[] from node.js to solidity function:

```
function test(string[] memory options) public {}
```

like this way:

```
const options = ["a","b","c"]
const contract = this.getContract();
const testFunc = contract.functions['test'];
await testFunc(options);
```

but got the error: invalid value for array;

Solidity pragma:

pragma solidity 0.6.5;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

Also, if I call a contract from Etherscan with the same value it works

Answer (score 0):

`contract.functions` is used in `ethers.js` ([docs](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract/#Contract--readonly)). Since your question is tagged `web3`, my answer is using the `web3` library.

Assuming that `this.getContract()` returns the `Contract` instance, you can execute a contract method using the `contract.methods` ([docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send)) object.

Use `.send()` to send a read-write transaction from your configured wallet, or `.call()` to make a read-only call.

```
const options = ["a","b","c"]
const contract = this.getContract();
await contract.methods.test(options).send();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is my mistake, I meant ether js, however, I tried this solution, but my contract doesn't have methods it has only functions.

"web3": "^1.3.0"
const Contract = require('web3-eth-contract');
const contact = new Contract(ABIInterface, address);

contract.methods.test(options).send(); => cann't get "test" of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Building on the previous answer and your comment about using ethers, this is how I would do this (I use ethers too - just update your dependencies' versions to save headaches if you can):

```
const options = ["a","b","c"]
//either this for deployed contract:
const contract = await ethers.getContractAt(contractABI, contractAddress, signer);
//or this, for undeployed contract:
contract = await ethers.getContractFactory("myContract");//your contract's name; //compile first
contract = await contract.deploy();
await contract.deploy();
// simplest foolproofer, can "prettify" for github later:
contract = contract.connect(signer);
//now for the real action:
await contract.test(options);
```